# WCF Service: The caller was not authenticated by the service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

**Edit:** Issue discovered, problem not solved.

I'm currently writing a WCF service library to access a Dynamics CRM 2011 server to gather a list of the visible organizations.

The code works well locally, however when accessing the service in a console application, I recieve the following error:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: The caller was not authenticated by the service. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.ThrowIfNegotiationFault(Message message, EndpointAddress target)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.GetNextOutgoingMessageBody(Message incomingMessage, SspiNegotiationTokenProviderState sspiState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IssuanceTokenProviderBase`1.DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpantimeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Discovery.IDiscoveryService.Execute(DiscoveryRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.DiscoveryServiceProxy.Execute(DiscoveryRequest request)
   at DHDServ.DHDServ.GetData(String serverName)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I am using active directory/Windows authentication and blocking anonymous users (the service is hosted on Windows Server 2008, but will be accessed by other machines). Due to inexperience, the web.config file is still quite barebones (from the Visual Studio 2010 template).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you require more information, please ask and I'll reply as soon as possible.

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Turn on CRM tracing to ensure that the request is getting to CRM, and not getting blocked by some incorrect web.config setting.

Comment: I'm unable to do that at the minute, however if I execute the 'IsAuthenticated' method on the DiscoveryServiceProxy object, it returns true (persumably meaning I am, in fact, authenticated.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to access CRM including where you set any credentials?

Comment: It appears to be a problem with our server connections.

Due to the way in which our servers are set-up, it doesn't handle a 'double hop' very well - leading to a Kerberos authentication error.

We have yet to solve this error, however this post is just to let you know the problem is resolved.

Thanks to all who helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the windows user you are running the command line as, is an active user AND has at least one role within CRM.  Also make sure you have the [WIF](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17331) installed.

Comment: @jas0n Does the user you're authenticating with have a role with CRM?

Comment: Yes, and the user has access to 3 organizations on the server in question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with our server connections.

Due to the way in which our servers are set-up, it doesn't handle a 'double hop' very well - leading to a Kerberos authentication error.

We have yet to solve this error, however this post is just to let you know the problem is resolved.

Thanks to all who helped :)

Comment: This is probably more appropriate as a comment as it doesn't actually provide a solution to the problem, you're just making a note that the issue has been resolved in some other fashion.

Comment: Apologies, being fairly new to contributing on Stack Overflow. At least I know now. Thanks :)